# Entity Framework 1 - 1 - * - 1 relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I want to get every instance of Job in which their worker's region is X from my entity context. How would I do this.

The relationships of my tables are as such:

```
Job to Worker = 1 - 1  
Worker to WorkerRegionGroup = 1 - 1..*  
WorkerRegionGroup to Region = 1..* - 1  //However is not explictly defined via the EF
```

### Tables

**bold means the primary key**

*Job*
**int ID**
string name
string description
int worker_id

*Worker*
**int ID**
string name
int WorkerRegionGroup_ID

*WorkerRegionGroup*
**int id**
int Worker_ID
int Region_ID

*Region*
**int ID**
string name

If there is a link that you can suggest that will help me better understand linq querys and the Entity Framework, please do post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jobs.where(job=> job.Worker
     .where(worker=> worker.WorkerRegionGroup.Region == x).Any());
```

Comment: I incorrectly labeled a relationship. The WorkersRegionGroup to Region is not explicitly defined, which I believe may actually be my problem.

Comment: Marking as the correct answer as i was able to correct my relationship mistake, Thank you!